# Questions about the divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am looking at the proof of the divergence theorem and I have some questions.

The proof of the divergence theorem

$$\iiint_D \nabla \cdot \overrightarrow{F} dV= \iint_S \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} ds$$

is the following:

[image]

$$z_1=f_1(x,y), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$z_2=f_2(x,y), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\overrightarrow{F}=M\hat{\imath}+N \hat{\jmath}+P \hat{k}$$

$$\hat{n}=\hat{\imath} \cos{\alpha}+\hat{\jmath} \cos{\beta}+ \hat{k} \cos{\gamma}$$

$$\iint_S \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n} d \sigma=\iint_S (M \cos{\alpha}+N \cos{\beta}+P \cos{\gamma}) d \sigma=\iiint_D(\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{z}})dxdydz$$

---

$$\iint_S M \cos{\alpha}d \sigma=\iiint_D \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{x}}dxdydz$$
$$\iint_S N \cos{\beta}d \sigma=\iiint_D \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{y}}dxdydz$$
$$\iint_S P \cos{\gamma}d \sigma=\iiint_D \frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{z}}dxdydz$$

---

$$\iint_S P \cos{\gamma}d \sigma=\iint_{S_1} P \cos{\gamma}d \sigma+\iint_{S_2} P \cos{\gamma}d \sigma$$

[image]

$$\hat{k} \cdot \hat{n_2}=\cos{\gamma_2}>0$$
$$\cos{\gamma_2}d \sigma=dxdy$$

[image]

$$\cos{\gamma_1}<0$$
$$\cos{\gamma_1} d \sigma=-dxdy$$

$$\\$$

$$\iint_S P \cos{\gamma} d \sigma=\iint_R P(x,y,z_2) dxdy-\iint_R P(x,y,z_1)dxdy=\iint_R[P(x,y,z_2)-P(x,y,z_1)]dxdy=\iint_R[\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{z}}dz]dxdy=\iiint_D \frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{z}}dxdydz$$

---

So $$\iiint_D \nabla \cdot \overrightarrow{F} d \overrightarrow{V}=\iint_S \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}d \sigma$$

---

$$$$

Are $z_1$ and $z_2$ the surfaces of $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively??

Why do we take at the beginning:
$\hat{n}=\hat{\imath} \cos{\alpha}+\hat{\jmath} \cos{\beta}+ \hat{k} \cos{\gamma}$ ??

Could you explain me the part where we prove that:
$\iint_S P \cos{\gamma}d \sigma=\iiint_D \frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{z}}dxdydz$ ??

Comment: $\cos \gamma d\sigma = dx dy$ and $\int \frac{dP}{dz}dz = P(z_1) - P(z_2)$ easy peasy

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I haven't understood why the relation $\cos{\gamma} d \sigma=dxdy$ stands. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: in your previous question $d\sigma = \Delta P_k$ and $dxdy = \Delta A_k$ ... just note that in this case, scalars are taken

Comment: In the previous question we had $\cos{\gamma}=\frac{\Delta A_k}{\Delta P_k}$, a normal vector of the plane $xy$ (the part $A_k$ ) is $\hat{k}$, and a normal vector of the surface ( the part $\Delta P_k$ ) is $\hat{n}$, right? So in this case why isn't it: 
$$\cos{\gamma}=\frac{\hat{k}}{\hat{n}}$$ but $$\cos{\gamma}=\hat{k} \cdot \hat{n_2}$$??

Comment: No :( ... $\Delta A_k$ and $\Delta P_k$ they are areas ,, one is projection area on xy plane and P_k is surface area. You cannot make it vanish.

Comment: also ... $\cos \gamma = \hat k \cdot \hat n = \Delta A_k/\Delta P_k = dxdy/d\sigma$ ... one does not simply divide a vector by vector.

Comment: Could you explain me why $\cos{\gamma_2}$ is equal to the product $\hat{k} \cdot \hat{n_2}$? I got stuck right now... :/

Comment: that is the definition of dot product $\vec A \cdot \vec B = |A||B|\cos \theta$ ... since these are unit vectors you get such values. and $\hat n_2$ is unit normal vector of surface and $\hat k$ is of plane.

Comment: Ok! I understand! But I still do not understand why $\cos{\gamma_2}d \sigma=dxdy$...Has it to do with the projection of the surface on the plane with angle $\gamma_2$??

Comment: yes it has something to do with **REGION** of projection rather than infinitesimals... this is a bit complicated. it's rather $$\iint_D \cos \gamma d\sigma = \iint_D dx dy $$

Comment: take few examples yourself ... like inclined planes (triangle) with intercepts $(1,2,3)$ and see yourself

Comment: Ahaaa... So is $d \sigma$ a part of the surface and it's projection at the plane is the part $dxdy$?? $$$$ I have also an other question...Why do we take at the beginning of the proof $$\hat{n}=\hat{\imath} \cos{\alpha}+ \hat{\jmath} \cos{\beta}+\hat{k} \cos{\gamma}$$??

Comment: Obvious lol ... they are direction cosines of the normal of the surface.

Comment: How did we find this $\hat{n}$??

Comment: $\hat n = \frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}$ where $F = F(x,y)$ a surface function.

Comment: Isn't $\overrightarrow{F}=M \hat{\imath}+N \hat{\jmath}+P \hat{k}$?

Comment: no ... here we are dealing with surface like $z= x^2 + y^2$ ... $\vec F = M \hat i + \dots $ is a field ... it's like ... looks like this
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFields_files/image003.gif

Comment: But the equation of the surface is not given, is it? How can we calculate  then the normal vector $\hat{n}$??

Comment: no region is given either ... assume there is a 3 dimentional region $R$ whose boundary is closed surface $\partial R$ ... take some Region (as you always have region in GVT) it's borders will form a closed surface which is what you need.

Comment: But how did we find $\hat{n}$ since the region/surface is not given? Do we suppose that is equal to $\hat{\imath} \cos{\alpha}+ \hat{\jmath} \cos{\beta} + \hat{k} \cos{\gamma}$??

Comment: suppose there is some smooth surface ... then at any point in that surface, $\hat n = \hat{\imath} \cos{\alpha}+ \hat{\jmath} \cos{\beta} + \hat{k} \cos{\gamma}$ that comes from geometry and calculus. it's called direction cosine. http://planetmath.org/surfacenormal

Comment: Ahaa..Ok! After the third picture, where $\cos{\gamma_1} <0$, why is there also a minus sign at 
$$\cos{\gamma_1} d \sigma=-dxdy$$ ??

Comment: And also why is $\cos{\gamma_2}>0$ and $\cos{\gamma_1}<0$ ??